# Installing Linux on MacBook (os X 10.5.8)

Tags: linux, macbook, multi-boot, boot-camp

Is there any way I can install and run Linux (any free flavor) natively on my MacBook? I mean without virtualization tools and software.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/) in order to do this. Start it in Mac OS X, it will ask you to partition your hard drive, insert bootable *Windows* CD/DVD and restart the computer. Of course you don't have to insert *Windows* CD, use Linux instead. When installation is finished, you have to press Option key on computer startup in order to select between Mac OS X and Linux.

I've installed Ubuntu on my Mac Book Pro. If that is your distro, I would recommend you to check for hardware compatibility first. Check out [Installing Ubuntu on a MacBook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook).